# how to run c++ target in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've set up a c++ project in VSCode using the tutorial at [1], which helps setting up a makefile and the debug target (which can be run with F5). Say I only want to compile (run `make`) and run the project (run `mytool` if succesful) using some keyboard shortcut, how do I set that up? (This seems like a pretty simple question, but apparently not easy to answer, and not easy to google either).

Thanks!

[1] https://www.paulbarrick.com/game-devlopment/game-development-on-linux-using-vscode-sdl2-and-opengl/

Comment: Edit your `tasks.json` and your `launch.json` to support the Makefile or use this: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-B is build, ctrl-F5 is run without debugging. Both of these options are menu items that tell you the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I understand it's possible to build (using ctrl-shift-b). But how do I build and run? I took at a look at the Makefile extension, it appears if you go from the project explorer to the makefile extension view, then there's a play button. But how do you run that with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: ..that will start the debugger. The question is how, do I run the target, without the debugger.

Comment: ctrl-f5 is supposed to run without the debugger while F5 is with the debugger

Comment: I see. It's not working to me -- ctl-f5 and f5 will either both debug or both not debug, depending on whether I've set "-g" as a compiler flag in the Makefile.

Comment: ...I have cleared all the vscode stuff out of the project folder and restarted importing the project into vscode using the Makefile extension -- the Makefile extension now provides a run and a run+debug buttons that work, but it doesn't set up build/run/debug tasks that vscode picks up. So the menu items run-start-debugging and run-without-debugging don't work, and the keyboard shortcuts don't work either. So it's a bit back to square one.

Comment: FYI, there is no C/C++ language.  You are programming in C++ or C.  You can mix C++ and C code, but that's not recommended (makes programs more difficult).

Comment: The problem of how to set up a build-run, build-run-debug targets to work with the keyboard shortcuts are independent of whether your makefile targets g++ or gcc.